# if an "url image" is equal to an image got by document.getElementsByTagName("img")?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to get all images and check if one of these images is equal to an image (specified by me) change it to another image (specified by me).
Thanks!

```
var object = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
//object[0].src is = to "image/image1.png";
if(object[0].src == "image/image1.png")   {
    object[0].src = "image/image2.png"
}
```

Comment: And the problem (if we ignore the fact that you set `.src` to the value you then compare it with in the `if` on the next line o.O) is?

Comment: You might want to use `object[0].src.includes("image/image1.png")` because `src` will return the absolute path.

Comment: @Andreas no im not setting it. if you see i comment it. it was to say that object[0].src in fact is image/image1.png so when i go to verifie it. if statement is false and that is the issue

Comment: Now, after you edited your question.

Comment: we are here to learn not to fight. however i said i comment it and not i COMMENTED it. and also if it was for setting don't make difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions by debugging!.

so i was trying to check if an image is equal to an image of the all images i got (specifing one of them for example the first image so object[0]) in var object by document.getElementsByTagName("src)

with this if: if(object[0].src == "image/image1.png) this return always false because object[0].src return file:///C:/Users/Name/Documents/foldername/image/image1.png" so checking if this is equal to "image/image1.png" return always false. and the **solution is**:

```
if(object[0].src == file:///C:/Users/Name/Documents/foldername/image/image1.png"){ 
         //do something
    }
```

to know the complete url: `alert(object[0].src);`

sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to check each image:

```
var images = [...document.getElementsByTagName("img")]

for (const image of images) {
    if (image.src === "image/image1.png") {
        // do something
        image.src = "somethingelse.png"
    }
}
```

`[...]` converts the `HTMLCollection` `document.getElementsByTagName` returns so you can iterate over it.